# Change url slug to camel case

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string in PHP:

```
this-is_a-test
```

I want to change that to this:

```
thisIsATest
```

So the string can contain any numer of dashes or underscores. I need some regex function that changes the string to a camel case string.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = 'this-is_a-test';

function toUpper($matches) {
  return strtoupper($matches[1]);
}

echo preg_replace_callback('/[-_](.)/', 'toUpper', $string); // thisIsATest
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/4Iq5T)**.

Answer (score 6):

Nah, you don't need regex for that.

- `str_replace()` to replace the punctuation with spaces.
- `ucwords()` to upper-case the first letter of each word.
- `str_replace()` again to get rid of the spaces.

You could use regex, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [lcfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php), [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [ucwords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) functions.

Exemple: `lcfirst(str_replace('-', '', ucwords('my-slug-string', '-')))`